# making a server chat

Tags: c#, tcp

I am not very familiar with server stuff I just know C# so I am not very familiar with the code below. I am trying to make a server chat the kind that will allow people on a server to chat with each other. I am talking about the kind of server you have at schools or workplaces. I am not sure though how to do this or how to use the below code IF it accomplishes this.

Overal what I am trying to accomplish is a chat among a group of people on the same server but am having great difficulty because I don't know a lot of server things.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MulticastChat : Form
{
   TextBox newText;
   ListBox results;
   Socket sock;
   Thread receiver;
   IPEndPoint multiep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1"), 9050);

   public MulticastChat()
   {
      Text = "Multicast Chat Program";
      Size = new Size(400, 380);

      Label label1 = new Label();
      label1.Parent = this;
      label1.Text = "Enter text string:";
      label1.AutoSize = true;
      label1.Location = new Point(10, 30);

      newText = new TextBox();
      newText.Parent = this;
      newText.Size = new Size(200, 2 * Font.Height);
      newText.Location = new Point(10, 55);

      results = new ListBox();
      results.Parent = this;
      results.Location = new Point(10, 85);
      results.Size = new Size(360, 18 * Font.Height);

      Button sendit = new Button();
      sendit.Parent = this;
      sendit.Text = "Send";
      sendit.Location = new Point(220,52);
      sendit.Size = new Size(5 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
      sendit.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonSendOnClick);

      Button closeit = new Button();
      closeit.Parent = this;
      closeit.Text = "Close";
      closeit.Location = new Point(290, 52);
      closeit.Size = new Size(5 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
      closeit.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonCloseOnClick);

      sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
      IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
      sock.Bind(iep);
      sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1")));
      receiver = new Thread(new ThreadStart(packetReceive));
      receiver.IsBackground = true;
      receiver.Start();
   }

   void ButtonSendOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
   {
      byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newText.Text);
      newText.Clear();
      sock.SendTo(message, SocketFlags.None, multiep);
   }

   void ButtonCloseOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
   {
      receiver.Abort();
      sock.Close();
      Close();
   }

   void packetReceive()
   {
      EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)multiep;
      byte[] data = new byte[1024];
      string stringData;
      int recv;
      while (true)
      {
         recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
         stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
         results.Items.Add("from " + ep.ToString() + ":  " + stringData);
      }
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
      Application.Run(new MulticastChat());
   }
}
```

Comment: wpf, winforms, asp.net ?

Comment: have you tested it?  What exactly is your question / problem?

Comment: When I run it I get the error ln 85 "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: my question is how can I accomplish a simple server chat not too code heavy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it does look like the code above at least achieved something similar to what you're asking I believe you'll be better off trying to clarify exactly what you need.

For instance why not just use a simple form which submits the chat text to the server, and displays to all users?  You would store each 'chat' into a database and show them all on a page ordered by time.  This could be set up to automatically poll the server at short intervals (or even [long poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)) and it would appear to users that they are chatting to each other.

Although not the most elaborate solution, I would say it appears to certainly be in reach for you.